# Postgres: Do you still separate data and indexes with SSDs

Tags: postgresql, layout, solid-state-drive

Are folks still keeping data and indexes separate for performance or do the current SSDs make this a quaint practice from the past?

Ive been presented with a new stand alone system with (12 4 TB ssd ) in 6 RAID0 mirrors with RAID1 stripe laid on top of them and presented as a single mount point (/pgdata/vd0).

Asking if other DBAs would ask to have this rebuilt and have heated interactions with the hardware guys or just run with it and put a datawarehouse on this?

Just asking at a high level

Comment: I've never seen this recommended in the first place with PostgreSQL.  (I have seen it recommended with Oracle, but generally not by people who seemed to know what they were doing.)

Comment: I agree. This is a kind of "urban myth" that may have had some foundation on Oracle systems 30 years ago, but it is not very relevant today. If you want to spread the load, use striping on a lower level.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a software development question. It would be a better fit for [dba.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is always "it depends". If the indexes typically fit in RAM, it won't matter. If the data you're pulling out includes large result sets from the disks, it probably won't make much of a difference since the random access on the HDDs will dominate the total interaction.

SSDs make a huge difference with [OLTP](https://www.guru99.com/oltp-vs-olap.html) workloads that make a lot of random access calls, but not just limited to the indexes. SSDs just make everything much faster.

This practice is also often superseded by options like [ZFS's Adaptive Replacement Cache](https://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/04/15/explanation-of-arc-and-l2arc/) which intelligently send reads/writes of the most used sectors to the SSD for speed in a similar fashion to [SSHDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive), but filesystem-based.

All that said, every database is different: in structure, in volume, and in usage patterns. The best way to tune both the hardware and the software is to test your specific use cases and profile the results. There are no silver bullets, and this includes the "index on an SSD" option.

Answer (score 1):

After doing testing on different raid configs and tablespace layouts, I found there was still a 15% performance gain with separating indexes from data with SSDs. Ended up with this config..and its fast!

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz

6 x 4TB SSD - RAID 10 - Single Mount Point
2 x 2TB SSD - RAID 10 - logs
2 x 2TB SSD - RAID10 - Indexes